# Is there a way to group service accounts in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

Within the same Google Cloud Platform organization I'm managing there are several service accounts belonging to different projects that need access to a single (separate) project.

**Is there any way to avoid having to individually grant access to each one of the service accounts to resources in the project via role?**

With *regular* user accounts (i.e. those logging in via @gmail.com or other domain credentials) this can be achieved by putting all of them in a group through Cloud Identity and binding the role, but I do not know if there is a way of doing this for service accounts.

Comment: Just an idea - are you able to create a group and add the email address of the service account to it? I doubt it, but please check first..

Comment: That should work, Graham.  I know that I've added a service account to a Google Group before.

Comment: Confirming here that service accounts can be added to a Google Group, haven't been able to verify that they got the access permissions inherited from it. Will report back once I test that.

Comment: So do we know if you can you add service accounts to gsuite groups? Is this supported

Comment: i can confirm that it is possible. also the service account get the permissions assigned to group.

Comment: I think you can use org policy to restrict service accounts group.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [Google groups](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group) which is a collection of Google accounts and service accounts to apply an access policy to a collection of users so that you would be able to grant and change access controls for a whole group at once instead of granting or changing access controls one-at-a-time for individual users or service accounts.

Comment: The only downfall to this method, that I can think of, is that you have to allow any email domains to be added to the group. So be careful about how the group is setup and what users are added.